# Mapping wp-login to primary domain on a Wordpress network

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress multi-site network setup so that all subdomains *.hosting.abc.com are a WP site in the network. I'm using Wordpress 3.6.

Most of the sites have custom domain mappings, for example, www.xyz.com points to xyz.hosting.abc.com. In the domain mappings settings, www.xyz.com is set as the primary.

Everything is working great except than when I visit www.xyz.com/wp-admin/ I get redirected to xyz.hosting.abc.com/wp-login.php but I expected I would get redirected to www.xyz.com/wp-login.php.

Is there a way to configure the network so that users aren't redirected away from their primary domain for the login?

Really, the main reason is that hosting.abc.com is not a real site and it has only dummy content. I don't want to draw attention to it, and for that matter, it got blocked by Bluecoat so people who work somewhere that uses Bluecoat for proxying can't log into their site. (yes, I'm one of the people blocked)